# Having problems with the usage of a block in Flask

Tags: python, flask, block

so I tried bulding a (small) website (for learning purposes) and had a few problems with the usage of a block.
I have the feeling that the problem is something obvious, but I can't figure it out.
Here is my code:

```
# main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("main.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
# main.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
# mainexdended.html
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block title %}Test{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<h1> Content Test </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, when I run the code, I just get a blank page. Everything defined in the mainextended.html gets ignored.
How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are rendering main.html, not mainextended.html.

You need to change

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("mainextended.html")
```

Than you should see the contents of both, main.html and mainextended.html

If you use "extend" you always want to render the "extending" html, there is also a function to include content tho, which would work the other way round.